# Turn an event handler.on() after you have turned the event handler .off()

Tags: jquery

jQuery newb here.

How can I go about turning an `event handler .on()` and `.off()` in such away that it is like a toggle?

I have an `.onClick event handler` bound to the `$(document)`, and when a user **does not** click on a specific field (`inputElement`), the `.onClick event handle`is "turned" `.off()`. How can I "turn" the `event handler` back `.on()` when the user **does** click on the specific field (`inputElement`)?

**This is my code thus far:**

```
$(document).on("click.viewHeaderInput", function (e){
    if (inputElement !== e.target) 
    {
        $(inputElement).blur();
        $(document).off("click.viewHeaderInput");
    }
});
```

**I thought of using something like this to "turn" the `event handler` back `.on()`, but realize this will not work, as the `event handler` is "turned `.off()`:**

```
$(".textInputTwo").on("click", function()
{

})
```

I appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `.off()` does not disable the event handler, it removes it ([see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/)) so nothing remains.

You need to run the exact same `.on()` code again to re-create what you created initially and which you then discarded by calling `.off()`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!